# Scraping and save data from URLs to csv using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

Well, I am new to BS in Python. I have written a code that scrapes HTML and save all the data that I need in csv file. The values from the ALL_NUMBERS file are substituted into the URL and thus a large number of URLs are obtained.

The code is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#--READ NAMES--
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}
all_names = [] # TO KEEP ALL NAMES IN MEMORY

with open('ALL_NUMBERS.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        line = line.strip()
        all_names.append(line)

url_template = 'https://www.investing.com/news/stock-market-news/learjet-the-private-plane-synonymous-with-the-jetset-nears-end-of-runway-{}'

all_urls = [] # TO KEEP ALL URLs IN MEMORY

with open("url_requests.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for name in all_names:
        url = url_template.format(name)
        print('url:', url)
        all_urls.append(url)
        text_file.write(url + "\n")

# --- read data ---

for name, url in zip(all_names, all_urls):
    # print('name:', name)
    # print('url:', url)
    r1 = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

page = r1.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
results = soup.find('div', class_= 'WYSIWYG articlePage')
para = results.findAll("p")
results_2 = soup.find('div', class_= 'contentSectionDetails')
para_2 = results_2.findAll ("span")
#for n in results_2:
    #print n.find('p').text

#cont = soup.select_one("div.contentSectionDetails")
#ram = cont.select_one("span")
#[x.extract() for x in ram.select_one('span')]


with open('stock_market_news_' + name + '.csv', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(str(para))
    text_file.write(str(para_2))
```

It works well, but only with one URL. I want to save **para** and **para_2** from each URL in one csv file. That is, save two parameters from each URL in each line:

| Text | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `para` From URL(1) | `para_2` From URL(1) |
| `para` From URL(2) | `para_2` From URL(2) |
| ... | ... |

Unfortunately, I don't know how do it better for a lot of URLs in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store all the params in a list and then save the result in your file:

```py
import csv

# ...

# --- read data ---

params = []
for name, url in zip(all_names, all_urls):
    r1 = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    page = r1.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
    results = soup.find('div', class_= 'WYSIWYG articlePage')
    para = '\n'.join([r.text for r in results.findAll("p")])
    results_2 = soup.find('div', class_= 'contentSectionDetails')
    para_2 = results_2.findAll("span")[0].text
    params.append([str(para), str(para_2)])

with open('stock_market_news_' + name + '.csv', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write("Text;Time\n")
    wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(['Text', 'Time'])
    wr.writerows(params)
```

Does this answer solve your problem?

Have a nice day!

Comment: There are some mistakes:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeffrey/Desktop/Exchanges/web_scraper/Scraper_For_InvestingCom_SavetoFile_Variant2.py", line 40, in <module>
    csv_params = '\n'.join([';'.join(p) for p in params])
  File "C:/Users/Jeffrey/Desktop/Exchanges/web_scraper/Scraper_For_InvestingCom_SavetoFile_Variant2.py", line 40, in <listcomp>
    csv_params = '\n'.join([';'.join(p) for p in params])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, ResultSet found
@HenriChab

Comment: Yop, try with the new version, I just had to cast the BS ResultSet in str when joining! By doing so, lists are casted in str, which means that all the `p` tags are gathered as a list in the column `Text`, is that what you want?

Comment: Almost, but there are in outer file each symbol of the text wrote in each cell...looking like a hell...

Comment: What do you expect? Would you like to have the all text as a unique string in the `Text` column?
If yes, try the final version I wrote.

Comment: There is the same mistake. I expecting that PARA will be in column TEXT  as string and PARA_2 will be in column TIME as string

Comment: Oups, left an undesired str() cast. Could you retry?

Comment: And don't you know how to avoid empty tags? I mean if there is no data on the web page, then just avoid and go to the next URL?

Comment: I just updated the answer to use the csv library. The previous solution did not escaped anything so if the text was containing a `;`, it would not have work. I advise you to use the new version :)

Comment: In your previous question, yep, you could use a `if` condition that adds to `params` only if `paraa` is not empty.